# It seem's it isn't passing a value to a parameter [Java]

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null

My Code goes like this. it's always return 0 or null;

In my `Encryptor Class`

```
public void encrypt(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    if (!dst.exists()) {
        dst.mkdir();
    }
    if (!dst.isDirectory()) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        if (!src.isDirectory()) {
            copyEncrypted(src, dst);
        } else {
            File[] files = src.listFiles();
            System.out.println("Encrypting...");
            for (File f : files) {
                copyEncrypted(f, dst);
                if (deleteOriginal) {
                    f.delete();
                }
            }
            InterfaceController ic = new InterfaceController();
            ic.fileList(files.length);
            //ic._notif.setText("GAGO");
            for (File file : files) {
                System.out.println(file);
            }
            //System.out.println(files.length + " files are encrypted");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

In my `InterfaceController Class` with a method `fileList` and an int parameter

```
private int fileListMain = 0
public void fileList(int List) {
    fileListMain = List;
    //_notif.setText(fileListMain + " files are encrypted successfully!");
}
```

so that's it. whenever I run the Main, and try to print the size of files. it always return 0 and when I tried to removed the value of fileListMain variable, it returns null. please help me to get rid of this. thank you in advanced! and this is my first query in stackoverflow. :)

Comment: Maybe your src's file path is wrong.

Comment: As @ramazankul says, this is nothing to do with passing parameters, but because `files` is an empty array.

Comment: It is not clear what is returning null. Or what `src` is. Please add more context and the exception stack trace to your question.

Comment: I'll added the full method. on the context Sir

Comment: What do you mean with "it's always return 0 or null" - these are `void` methods, they don't retrun anything.

Comment: @Hulk in the fileList(int List) void method in my InterfaceController. seems can't obtained the value which came from the Encryptor Class (ic.fileList(files.length)); so the fileListMain return's null or 0;

Comment: Why is `fileListMain` a field on your `InterfaceController`-class? I'm confused about what you wan to achieve there. How do you know it is set to `0`? Did you already try to step through your code with a debugger?

Comment: @Hulk Yes, I already debugged it. and it's not working also, what I wanted to happens is to show the number of encrypted files which came from Encryptor Class. and the fileListMain is in the InterfaceController since this is my first stage as I developed it in JFX. InterfaceController has an element of TextArea and I wanted to print it on that element so it looks like, _notif.setText(fileListMain+": files are encrypted Successfully");

pardon for my english.